# Unable to map predictions to JavaRDD

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd, apache-spark-mllib

I'm trying to map the predictions the LinearRegression model in order to pass them onto the BinaryClassificationMetrics boject:

```
// Make predictions on test documents. cvModel uses the best model found (lrModel).
DataFrame predictions = cvModel.transform(testingFrame);
JavaRDD<Tuple2<Object, Object>> scoreAndLabels = predictions.map(
        new Function<Row, Tuple2<Object, Object>>() {
            @Override
            public Tuple2<Object, Object> call(Row r) {
                Double score = r.getDouble(1);
                return new Tuple2<Object, Object>(score, r.getDouble(0));
            }
        }
);
BinaryClassificationMetrics metrics
        = new BinaryClassificationMetrics(JavaRDD.toRDD(scoreAndLabels));
```

However, when I call `predictions.map(...)`, I get the following compilation error:

```
method map in class DataFrame cannot be applied to given types;
  required: Function1<Row,R>,ClassTag<R>
  found: <anonymous Function<Row,Tuple2<Object,Object>>>
  reason: cannot infer type-variable(s) R
    (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
  where R is a type-variable:
    R extends Object declared in method <R>map(Function1<Row,R>,ClassTag<R>)
```

Any suggestions on how to map the data of the predictions DataFrame?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out! I had to convert the DataFrame into an JavaRDD and from there on it was straight forward:

```
DataFrame predictions = cvModel.transform(testingFrame);
JavaRDD<Tuple2<Object, Object>> scoreAndLabels = predictions.toJavaRDD().map(
        new Function<Row, Tuple2<Object, Object>>() {
            @Override
            public Tuple2<Object, Object> call(Row r) {
                Double score = r.getDouble(4);
                Double label = r.getDouble(1);
                return new Tuple2<Object, Object>(score, label);
            }
        });

BinaryClassificationMetrics metrics
        = new BinaryClassificationMetrics(JavaRDD.toRDD(scoreAndLabels));
```

Comment: You should accept this. There is no reason to keep this open any longer :)